# Counting Duplicates In Sub Array and assigning to property

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, nested, duplicates

I have an array of objects with a nested array in which I would like to count duplicate occurances and map them to a counter property.

Input Array:

```
initialArr = [
              {
               id: 99,
               days: [{date: '2022-08-01'},
                      {date: '2022-08-03'},
                      {date: '2022-08-03'},
                      {date: '2022-08-01'}]
              },
              {
               id: 100,
               days: [{date: '2022-08-01'},
                      {date: '2022-08-02'},
                      {date: '2022-08-02'}]
               }
              ]
```

Expected output array with counter property:

```
outputArr = [
              {
               id: 99,
               days: [{date: '2022-08-01', count: 2},
                      {date: '2022-08-03', count: 2},
                     ]
              },
              {
               id: 100,
               days: [{date: '2022-08-01', count: 1},
                      {date: '2022-08-02', count: 2},
               }
              ]
```

What is the best way to go about this? I have tried a couple methods using map and reduce but I'm running into difficulties with the nesting of the arrays. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working inside to out, start with the days array...

```
function removeDupDays(days) {
  // this produces { dateString: [{date: 'dateString'}, ...
  const grouped = days.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (!acc[el.date]) acc[el.date] = [];
    acc[el.date].push(el);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(grouped).map(date => {
    return { date, count: grouped[date].length };
  });
}
```

Use that in a function fixes object's days prop

```
// given an object with a days prop, remove dup days
function removeObjectDupDays(object) {
  return { ...object, days: removeDupDays(object.days) };
}
```

Map that over the initial array...

```
const arrayWithoutDupDays = initialArr.map(removeObjectDupDays);
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed. Definitely got caught up trying to do it all in one go!

Comment: :-) @Code4fun, "decomposition" is my favorite trick.  Kind of the opposite of a lot of virtuosos you might find on SO, who can perform a miracle with one, inscrutable line.